# How to return to v1 reload in v2 view

Tags: ios

I have two views
Controller, v1 displays the name and gender. Click to modify and go to v2. After the modification is completed (using firebase), confirm and return to v1, but v1 does not update the data..

I return v1 using

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I tried to use it, but the MainTabBar will disappear, and I can only return to the MainTabBarController directly (this method is too far away from v1)

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "v1")
            GetWindow()?.rootViewController = viewController
            GetWindow()?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

```
func GetWindow() -> UIWindow? {
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let sceneDelegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        return sceneDelegate?.window ?? appDelegate?.window
    } else {
        
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        return appDelegate?.window
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `GetWindow`? If it's a class then it seems that you are creating two different instances.

Comment: I edited the question and wrote GetWindow, can you help me where I am wrong? Thank you

Comment: Messing around with root view controllers and windows is definitely not the answer here. You need to look at how V1 fetches the data.  When v2 updates the data, how does V1 find out? You can use a Firestore snapshot observer or just share a data model between the two view controllers